# MongoDB crash on start (aborted with signal 6) CentOS 6.2 - Azure

Tags: mongodb, azure, centos

I'm trying to install MongoDB on CentOS 6.2 but it keeps crashing when ever I try to start it. I get the following errors:

```
mongod --dbpath /mnt/datadrive/data --logpath /mnt/datadrive/data/mongod.log
Tue May  7 14:47:46.913 terminate() called, printing stack (if implemented for platform):
0xdcf361 0x6ce59e 0x3b14ebcbe6 0x3b14ebcc13 0x3b14ebcd0e 0x3b14e61ce7 0x3b14ebaa04     0x3b14e663bc 0x3b14e67226 0xdecc8f 0xded5db 0xdea280 0x9e846f 0x6dc742 0x6de4d9 0x3b11a1ecdd 0x6ce389 
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xdcf361]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo11myterminateEv+0x3e) [0x6ce59e]
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6() [0x3b14ebcbe6]
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6() [0x3b14ebcc13]
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6() [0x3b14ebcd0e]
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZSt21__throw_runtime_errorPKc+0x67) [0x3b14e61ce7]
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6() [0x3b14ebaa04]
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSt6locale5_ImplC2EPKcm+0x4c) [0x3b14e663bc]
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSt6localeC2EPKc+0x5f6) [0x3b14e67226]
 mongod(_ZN5boost11filesystem34path21wchar_t_codecvt_facetEv+0x4f) [0xdecc8f]
 mongod(_ZNK5boost11filesystem34path14root_directoryEv+0xbb) [0xded5db]
 mongod(_ZN5boost11filesystem38absoluteERKNS0_4pathES3_+0x40) [0xdea280]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo27initializeServerGlobalStateEb+0x15f) [0x9e846f]
 mongod() [0x6dc742]
 mongod(main+0x9) [0x6de4d9]
 /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x3b11a1ecdd]
 mongod(__gxx_personality_v0+0x499) [0x6ce389]
Tue May  7 14:47:46.918 Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

Tue May  7 14:47:46.922 Backtrace:
0xdcf361 0x6cf729 0x3b11a32920 0x3b11a328a5 0x3b11a34085 0x6ce5a3 0x3b14ebcbe6 0x3b14ebcc13 0x3b14ebcd0e 0x3b14e61ce7 0x3b14ebaa04 0x3b14e663bc 0x3b14e67226 0xdecc8f 0xded5db 0xdea280 0x9e846f 0x6dc742 0x6de4d9 0x3b11a1ecdd 
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xdcf361]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10abruptQuitEi+0x399) [0x6cf729]
 /lib64/libc.so.6() [0x3b11a32920]
 /lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35) [0x3b11a328a5]
 /lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175) [0x3b11a34085]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo11myterminateEv+0x43) [0x6ce5a3]
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6() [0x3b14ebcbe6]
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6() [0x3b14ebcc13]
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6() [0x3b14ebcd0e]
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZSt21__throw_runtime_errorPKc+0x67) [0x3b14e61ce7]
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6() [0x3b14ebaa04]
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSt6locale5_ImplC2EPKcm+0x4c) [0x3b14e663bc]
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSt6localeC2EPKc+0x5f6) [0x3b14e67226]
 mongod(_ZN5boost11filesystem34path21wchar_t_codecvt_facetEv+0x4f) [0xdecc8f]
 mongod(_ZNK5boost11filesystem34path14root_directoryEv+0xbb) [0xded5db]
 mongod(_ZN5boost11filesystem38absoluteERKNS0_4pathES3_+0x40) [0xdea280]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo27initializeServerGlobalStateEb+0x15f) [0x9e846f]
 mongod() [0x6dc742]
 mongod(main+0x9) [0x6de4d9]
 /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x3b11a1ecdd]
```

I've been following a tutorial [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/common-tasks/mongodb-on-a-linux-vm/).
Any suggestions of how to fix this?

Comment: Trying setting your locale to something different before starting.
See [JIRA SERVER ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9032)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ended up being a Mac problem using SSH in terminal to connect to the VM. To solve this problem go to:

Terminal ⟶ Preferences ⟶ Profiles ⟶ Advanced

and uncheck the "*Set locale environment variables on startup*" checkbox under the **International** heading.

Answer (score 7):

Simply sharing another simpler (IMO) way to set a locale that I found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/UaR3vpduKX4/n3PK_HeIxUgJ) while searching for a solution to this issue.

Essentially, set your locale to a sane value for e.g.

```
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

The bug report is [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9032).